# Limit of p-adic numbers

Tags: p-adic-number-theory

Let $\alpha\in\mathbb{Z}_p^\times$. I read somewhere that the limit of $\alpha^{n!}$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$ is equal to one. Can someone explain to me why this is? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint : $a^k\equiv 1\ (\ mod\ p\ )$ , whenever $p-1|k$

Now, use $p-1|n!$ for all $n\ge p-1$.

Comment: Got it, thanks!

Comment: I’m not sure I see your argument clear. I see that $a^{(p-1)!}=1+pz$ for some $p$-adic integer $z$, but have you shown that the higher powers get closer to $1$ than that?